# Is there anything special about codes for which $n=k+d$?

Tags: coding-theory

This question isn't particularly well-defined, but I am curious if there is any kind of classification of codes of where $n=k+d$. Under what circumstances does a code like this exist? (Specify whatever field you like, or whether it's linear or non-linear). I see a special case of this question here for (linear) [2k,k,k]-codes, : [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510612/linear-2k-k-k-codes)

Does this give any insight into the more general inquiry presented above?  This isn't homework or anything like that -- it is only a question I thought of while reading that I could not find an answer for anywhere on MSE. Anything interesting that can be gleaned from codes of this type would be interesting to know.

Comment: Codes for which $n-k+1 = d$ are called MDS (maximum-distance-separable) codes and there is quite a bit of literature about them. So I guess what you are looking for could be called "near-MDS" codes. Try searching for them on the Internet.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind immediately is the huge family of Goppa codes, aka Algebraic Geometry codes. Codes based on an algebraic curves of genus $g$ are "within $g$ of being MDS". When $g=0$ the approach gives the Reed-Solomon codes. When $g=1$ we have codes based on elliptic curves. The point of allowing a gap of $g$ to MDS is that we can then get longer codes. When $g=0$ we stuck with $n\ge q+1$ ($q$ is the size of the alphabet). More generally, we have the bound $n\ge q+2g\sqrt{q}$. This is not actually that much, which is why in practice people stick to RS.

Comment: My proofreading sucks. Ok, it is non-existent. The inequalities in the comment above should be the other way around. The maximum length of an RS-code is $n=q+1$ (more typically, when using generator polynomials, you have $n\le q-1$. With AG-codes we have $n\le q+1+2g\sqrt{q}$, allowing longer codes. A big selling point for AG-codes was/is that asymptotically they allow extremely good codes when $q\ge49$. Then $q$ is constant and both $g$ and $n$ grow.